# Can I listen to CMPedometer in the background and send a local push notification upon different conditions?

Tags: ios, ios8, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, background-process

This is an iOS question.

What I'd like to do is listen to the built-in pedometer (CMPedometer) while the app is in the background. When the pedometer activity changes (from "walking" to "running" to "not moving," etc) I'd like the option to send a local push notification to the user's device.

For example, the app sits in the background. When I start moving, I get a push notification saying, "you're moving!" When I stop moving, I get a push notification saying, "you've stopped moving!"

At the moment, I've got "location updates" set for my background mode. And the app will run in the background for about 15 minutes and track location and do what I want (trigger push notifications when pedometer data changes). But after 15 minutes, it stops altogether.

Is what I'm describing even possible on the device? If so, what am I doing wrong that the app times out after 15 minutes?

Happy to provide more details, but I don't want to overload this already long question!

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to get live activity updates when your app is suspended.

If you want to track user's activity, like walking, running, etc, use `CMMotionActivityManager`.

> Motion data reflects whether the user is walking, running, in a vehicle, or stationary for periods of time.

According to the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionActivityManager_class/index.html):

Updates are not delivered while the application is suspended, the application may use `queryActivityStartingFromDate:toDate:toQueue:withHandler:` to get activities from the time when the application was suspended.

So the best way to track user's activity in the background is using **background fetch**, and set the fetch interval to minimum.

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum)
```

Comment: setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval and UIApplication are iOS APIs.. which aren't practical when the app is running on the watch away from phone, like on a run or hike.  How do you do the background fetches with watchOS only, WITHOUT phone dependency?